# Display terms for multiple Woocommerce custom taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I need an imploded list of terms from three custom Woocommerce taxonomies including the taxonomy name to display in the product loop. I'll also need to be able to display multiple terms for each taxonomy. However, I can only get it to work with one taxonomy. And I can't figure out how to display the corresponding taxonomy name.

My custom taxonomies are 'artists', 'illustrators' and 'authors'.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Robert Douglas (Author), Bill Johnston (Illustrator), Kyle McBeth (Artist)

```
function list_author_terms() {
    global $post;
    $person = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'authors', 'artists', 'illustrators');
    if (    $person
     && !is_wp_error(  $person )
    ) {
    @usort( $person, function ( $a, $b )
    {
    return strcasecmp( 
            $a->slug,
            $b->slug
        );
    });
    // Display your terms as normal
    $term_list = [];
    foreach ( $person as $term ) 
       $term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '"class="author rsc-tp">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '<span class="attribute"> (Author)</span> </a>';
       $term_names[] = $term->name;
     echo implode( ', ', $term_list);
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add follows code snippet to achieve your task -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'list_author_terms', 6 );
function list_author_terms(){
    $taxonomies = array( 'authors', 'artists', 'illustrators' );
    $pro_list_terms = array();
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $term_obj_list = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
        $tax_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
        if( $term_obj_list && ! is_wp_error( $term_obj_list ) ){
            foreach ( $term_obj_list as $term ) {
                $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
                $pro_list_terms[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="author rsc-tp">' . $term->name . ' (' .$tax_obj->labels->singular_name . ')</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo join( ', ', $pro_list_terms );
}
```

Comment: This is so close! However, I need it to add (' . $tax_obj->labels->singular_name . ') to each term as well as a link to that term. For example, if we had multiple authors it would display like so: Joe Calahan (Author), Bart Simpson (Author). The html would be: <a href="link_to_term" class="author rsc-tp"> Joe Calahan (author)</a>, <a href="link_to_term" class="author rsc-tp"> Bart Simpson (author)</a>.

Comment: @MatthewAnderson I just updated above codes as per your needs. Please check.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I owe you a coffee, brother!

Comment: I tried to buy you a coffee, but I got the following error: 
This recipient accepts PayPal payments only through their website. To complete this payment, please go to their website and follow their instructions, or email the recipient for instructions.
If you continue to encounter problems, please contact customer service.

Comment: No worries. You can do the same from my [blog](https://itzmekhokan.wordpress.com/)